# I want to display message for client after successful insertion of data to database..so how to implement this using alert() message in javascript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, ado.net

Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.Odbc

Partial Class ADD_Employee
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim cons, query As String
    Dim con As OdbcConnection
    Dim cmd As OdbcCommand
    cons = "dsn=Courier; UID=Courier; PWD=123;"
    con = New OdbcConnection(cons)
    con.Open()
    If (RadioButton1.Checked) Then
        query = "insert into EMPLOYEE values('" & TextBox1.Text & "','" & TextBox2.Text & "','" & TextBox3.Text & "','" & "Male" & "','" & TextBox6.Text & "','" & TextBox4.Text & "','" & TextBox5.Text & "')"
        cmd = New OdbcCommand(query, con)
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

    End If
    If (RadioButton2.Checked) Then
        query = "insert into EMPLOYEE values('" & TextBox1.Text & "','" & TextBox2.Text & "','" & TextBox3.Text & "','" & "Female" & "','" & TextBox6.Text & "','" & TextBox4.Text & "','" & TextBox5.Text & "')"
        cmd = New OdbcCommand(query, con)
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End If


    con.Close()
End Sub
```

End Class

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like this

```
me.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(me.GetType(), "message", "alert('records has been inserted to the database!');", True)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
me.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me.[GetType](),"Data Added","alert('Success!');")
```

Answer (score 0):

RegisterStartupScript as described in previous answers is the way to do it.

However, are you sure you want to use alert? In terms of user experience it is not advised. You should take a look in some websites to see how it is done. For example, once I post this answer (and I guess it is added to some database), I will not get an alert, but rather a more delicate message. So I would suggest to have some "success" label, and change its Visible property to true, or maybe use Response.Redirect and redirect the user to a whole success page, it all depends on the experience you want to give to your users.